# Know the size of a file or image, using its base64

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, base64

I have an app in ionic that uploads images and pdf with a plugin, which returns all the information I need except the file size, this returns the base64 of the file but I need to validate that it is not greater than 3mb

```
this.chooser.getFile()
.then((file) => {
  console.log(file.dataURI)
});
```

This returns the base64 of the file, but how do I know the size of the file to validate that it is not greater than 3mb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the size

```
const base64str =  base64Data.split('base64,')[1];
const decoded = atob(base64str);
const size = decoded.length
```